# Can ember-cli watch and build automatically without running the server?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Title is pretty much my question. I'm serving the `dist` directory differently and would still like the benefit of auto-builds but I don't need to run the server. I looked in the docs and the cli help but didn't see anything specific. I know the cli help doesn't contain everything because it doesn't list `ember build` which is available.

Comment: What version of the cli are you using? [ember build is in the ember --help](http://imgur.com/75R80iH) and on the [ember-cli](http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-ember-cli) website...

Comment: `ember build --watch --output-path=yourCustomPath/`

Comment: Must have just missed it. Sorry about that. Good to know it is there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are wanting the `ember build` command to watch for changes in the file tree and rebuild on a change?

They implemented `ember build --watch` a while back which will trigger when a file changes. Tested just now and it worked on 0.2.7. Not sure what version it came in though. Let me know if this is not the answer you are looking for.